# Convert haskell Int with leading zero to String

Tags: string, haskell, int

Suppose I have a variable of type Int = 08, how can I convert this to String keeping the leading zero?

For instance:

```
v :: Int
v = 08

show v
```

Output: 8

I want the output to be "08".

Is this possible?

Comment: Ops, the output is actually "8", not 8.

Comment: Um, saying v = 08 is the same as saying v = 8 or v = 008 or v = 0000008. There is no way to get back the information of how many 0s you had defined v using. You can only print it with a certain number of 0s, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you are planning to do you might want to store the "08" as a string and only convert to int when you need the value.

Comment: Doing opposite sounds better. Store it as int and change it to string for displaying purposes.

Answer (score 24):

Use `Text.Printf.printf`:

```
printf "%02d" v
```

Make sure to import `Text.Printf.printf` first.

Comment: it is just `import Text.Printf`

Comment: Or `import Text.Printf (printf)`

Answer (score 8):

Its 8, not 08 in variable *v*. Yes, you assigned it 08 but it receives 8. Thats the reason *show* method displayed it as 8. You can use [the work around given by Mipadi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/376982/1477667).

**Edit:**

Output of a test.

```
Prelude> Text.Printf.printf "%01d\n" 08
8
Prelude> Text.Printf.printf "%02d\n" 08
08
Prelude> Text.Printf.printf "%03d\n" 08
008
```

Output of another test.

```
Prelude> show 08
"8"
Prelude> show 008
"8"
Prelude> show 0008
"8"
```

I hope you get the point.

**Edit:**

Found another workaround. Try this,

```
"0" ++ show v
```

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` way is probably best, but it's easy enough to write your own function:

```
show2d :: Int -> String 
show2d n | length (show n) == 1 = "0" ++ (show n)
         | otherwise = show n
```

Works as follows:

```
Prelude> show2d 1
"01"
Prelude> show2d 10
"10"
Prelude> show2d 100
"100"
```